# Azure: Blob Trigger throwing Error in web Jobs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, blogs, azure-webjobs

I am trying to create a webjob with blog trigger and my motive to create to automate some process whenever new blog uploaded in container.

i have write few line of code to test weather my webjob is working or not,but it's not working and throwing below error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233088
Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Can you help me to short out the issue:

I am attaching snapshot whatever i write to achieve this.

[Please see snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzea4.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to repro the issue. Look at the below code sample which works fine for me.

```
        static void Main()
    {
        CreateDemoData();
        // The connection string is read from App.config
        JobHost host = new JobHost();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    private static void CreateDemoData()
    {
        string connectionString = AmbientConnectionStringProvider.Instance.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringNames.Storage);
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("input");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("BlobOperations.txt");
        blob.UploadText("Hell!");

        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("persons");
        queue.CreateIfNotExists();

        Person person = new Person()
        {
            Name = "Mohit",
            Age = 30
        };

        queue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person)));
    }
```

Reference to Git Hub Project: [Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK Samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples)

Comment: Thanks mohit for quick suggestions.

Comment: issue was in connection string,i have not updated connection string on azure portal under application setting section for app service.it runs successfully once i updated storage account connection string in azure portal.